# Do peoples' names affect their choice of career?

Tags: psychology

The classic purported around the interwebs is of Dennis the Dentist or Lawrence the Lawyer - the idea that a person is likely to choose a career or place to live because it reminds them of their name. I've read some contrary reports on this but [this paper: "Why Susie Sells Seashells by the Seashore: Implicit Egotism and Major Life Decisions"](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/susie.pdf) seems to be the origin. So is this a real phenomenon and is the decision really about people's own names? Is it more likely to be a form of pareidolia from those conducting the studies? I'm skeptical of the claim for many reasons, but there seems to be a reported correlation at least.

Comment: you mean are [meaningful names](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MeaningfulName) more common than randomness can account for? seems to me like a confirmation bias plays a large role here

Comment: Confirmation bias from those conducting the studies you mean? I suppose one could argue that the confirmation bias they have is the same mechanism that makes 'Louise' move to 'Louisiana', etc. They apparently found disproportionate number of Jacks living in Jacksonville too. Would just be interesting to see if people really are affected so drastically by their own names.

Comment: New Scientist had a series of (non-serious) items on "[nominative determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism)"

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick  "Hunt's example is an article on incontinence in the British Journal of Urology .... by A. J. Splatt and D. Weedon" That's too funny not to be a pure coincidence. :P

Comment: A disproportionate number of Jacks in Jacksonville could be the bias of parents when naming their children, rather than the other way around. To a lesser degree, parental pressure could also affect career choice ("We named him Lawrence, because we knew he'd be a lawyer.")

Comment: @Flimzy - yeah, that's true. Also, a few have speculated that at least *some* of the Dennis/Dentist coincidences might be due to social status as well, as in, Dennis might be a name chosen by more middle to upper-class families whose children are more likely to be dentists and doctors, etc.

Comment: Isn't there a chapter in *Freakonomics* about how certain names are chosen only by lower class white trash parents thereby sending a dangerous signal to their future prospective employers?

Comment: @matt_black: I don't recall them using derogatory terms like "white trash", or suggest it was a signal to employers. (To be fair, it's been a few years since I read it.)

Comment: @Oddthinking I may also have misremembered their language, but I'm sure I've got the argument right.

Comment: The ancient Romans said "Nomen omen", the name is an omen.

Comment: Seems to me like keeping the hits and forgetting the misses

Comment: It seems there might be some debate between the author and a detractor here: [link](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/02/dennis_the_dent/) but obviously I can't tell if it's the actual Brett Pelham.